# Iterating over string with register

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to write a program that iterates over a string and writes each character to output one character at a time, I'm trying to use a register as an iterator like in a for loop to then index into the string but I get the error 'invalid operand type'

I'm setting r10 to 0

```
mov r10, 0
```

and later in the code after i increment r10 I'm trying to index a string like this but I'm getting errors

```
mov rsi, hello_str + r10
```

this works fine when I do this

```
mov rsi, hello_str + 1
```

The code:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:  mov rsi, hello_str
         mov r10, 0
loop:    mov rax, 1
         mov rdi, 1
         mov rsi, test + r10 
         ; when i do mov rsi, test + 1 it prints 'e' as expected
         ; when i do mov rsi, test it prints 'H' as expected
         mov rdx, 1
         syscall

         inc r10
         cmp rsi + r10, 0x00
         jne loop


section .data
hello_str: db "Hello, World!", 0xA
```

Thank you

Comment: `lea rsi, [hello_str + r10]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To calculate a pointer at runtime from a register and a static address**, you can use
**`lea rsi, [hello_str + r10]`**

(Requires a `reg + disp32` addressing mode, so only works in non-PIE executables on Linux where static data is in the low 2GB of virtual address space.)

Or to *iterate*, use `lea rsi, [rel hello_str]` outside the loop, then use `inc rsi` to go to the next byte.  (`syscall` doesn't destroy `rsi`).  Or obviously much better, pass a longer length to one `write` syscall.

---

**`mov rsi, hello_str + 1` is calculated at assemble+link time**, so there's no way to include a runtime register value in the calculation.  The source operand for a mov-immediate has to be a build-time constant.  Instructions that calculate something from a register have a different mnemonic: the syntax for `LEA` uses memory-operand syntax.

To *load* from memory, you'd want `movzx esi, byte [hello_str + r10]` to zero-extend a byte from memory into RSI.